# PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class Emogrifier, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to inline CSS with a html content which works perfect but only once. When I try it multiple times I'm getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Emogrifier, because the name is already in use

The error is thrown in the email-functions.php which gets included in my WordPress child theme functions.php file:

```
/**
 * Include email functions for ultimate member
 */
require 'ultimate-member/functions/email-functions.php';
```

---

This is the function in the email-functions.php file which causes the problem:

```
/**
 * Apply css to UM email message from template
 */
add_filter( 'um_email_send_message_content', 'apply_style_to_email', 10, 99);
function apply_style_to_email($message, $slug, $args ) {

    //Get Emogrifier class
    include_once get_home_path() . 'wp-content/themes/DiviChild/ultimate-member/libraries/class-emogrifier.php';

    ob_start();
    include_once get_home_path() . 'wp-content/themes/DiviChild/woocommerce/emails/email-styles.php';
    $css = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_styles', ob_get_clean() );

    // apply CSS styles inline for picky email clients.
    try {
        $emogrifier = new Emogrifier( $message, $css );
        $message    = $emogrifier->emogrify();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $logger = wc_get_logger();
        $logger->error( $e->getMessage(), array( 'source' => 'emogrifier' ) );
    }

    return $message;
}
```

As you can see I'm using include_once to get the Emogrifier class. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the Emogrifier class: https://codeshare.io/50B0ml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error describes your problem quite well. It looks like there are 2 classes with the same name in your project. Here a NameSpace could help you.

It's best to search your project files for the keyword "emogrifier", maybe you have the class 2 times in the project. Or the class comes from one of the vendor directories via Composer, but that should not happen with the Composer Packages NameSpaces.

http://php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
require_once( $vendorDir . '/wooemailcut304/includes/emogrifier/Emogrifier.php' );
```

Comment: Please extend your answer with further information and explanations, so it is not just an unexplained block of code.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use `require_once()`, which does exactly what it says.

If you `require()` a file that has already been `require`d, PHP doesn't care:  it reads the source-file again, leading to this error.  Whereas, `require_once()` will read the source-file only if it hasn't already been read before.

Comment: Replace include_one with require_one but the issue is still there: [12-Nov-2018 14:34:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Emogrifier, because the name is already in use